# How do I transform a List<String[]> to an XML Object using XMLMapper (Jackson)?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have a table that is represented as a `List<String[]>`. The first element of the list is the header and each other element is a row. I do not know the structure of the List ahead of time, so creating a class containing the properties/fields is not an option.

Imagine I have a table (let's call it 'Database') that looks like this:

```
Age|Name|Sex
23 |John|Male
19 |Sam |Female
18 |Alex|Male
```

The first element of the list would be a string array looking like this: 
["Age", "Name", Sex"] while the rows would look something like this ["23", "John", "Male"]

How do I get an XML output looking like this:

```
<Table name="Database">
<Row name="1">
    <Item name="Age">23</Item>
    <Item name="Name">John</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Male</Item>
</Row>
<Row name="2">
    <Item name="Age">19</Item>
    <Item name="Name">Sam</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Female</Item>
</Row>
<Row name="3">
    <Item name="Age">18</Item>
    <Item name="Name">Alex</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Male</Item>
</Row>
```

Basically I'm handed an input of a table, I run my algorithm and get a List as a return with the first element being a header. I've tried using XMLMapper and it works for mapping it to an XML quickly, but I don't get the format/structure I want.

```
public String createXMLObject() throws IOException {
List<String[]> table = extractData(); //extractData() is my custom method 
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(table);
mapper.writeValue(new File("test.xml"), table);
System.out.println(result);
return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want every `XML Node` named `Node`? Not `<table><item><age>18</age>....</item></table>` ?

Comment: @MichałZiober Sure, item works fine for me. It'll update it.

Comment: Create classes `Table`, `Row`, and `Item`, then convert `List<String[]>` to objects, and finally convert `Table` object to XML. The purpose of an **Object**Mapper is to convert **objects**, so you have to create objects first, that match the XML you want to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the overhead of Jackson for this, especially since you'd have to convert the data into a different format first anyway.

Just use StAX, like this:

```java
List<String[]> table = Arrays.asList(
        new String[] { "Age", "Name", "Sex"    },
        new String[] { "23" , "John", "Male"   },
        new String[] { "19" , "Sam" , "Female" },
        new String[] { "18" , "Alex", "Male"   } );

XMLStreamWriter xml = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
xml.writeStartElement("Table");
xml.writeAttribute("name", "Database");

String[] header = table.get(0);
for (int rowNo = 1; rowNo < table.size(); rowNo++) {
    String[] row = table.get(rowNo);
    xml.writeCharacters(System.lineSeparator());
    xml.writeStartElement("Row");
    xml.writeAttribute("name", String.valueOf(rowNo));
    for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < header.length; colIdx++) {
        xml.writeCharacters(System.lineSeparator() + "    ");
        xml.writeStartElement("Item");
        xml.writeAttribute("name", header[colIdx]);
        xml.writeCharacters(row[colIdx]);
        xml.writeEndElement(); // </Item>
    }
    xml.writeCharacters(System.lineSeparator());
    xml.writeEndElement(); // </Row>
}

xml.writeCharacters(System.lineSeparator());
xml.writeEndElement(); // </Table>
xml.close();
```

*Output*

```xml
<Table name="Database">
<Row name="1">
    <Item name="Age">23</Item>
    <Item name="Name">John</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Male</Item>
</Row>
<Row name="2">
    <Item name="Age">19</Item>
    <Item name="Name">Sam</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Female</Item>
</Row>
<Row name="3">
    <Item name="Age">18</Item>
    <Item name="Name">Alex</Item>
    <Item name="Sex">Male</Item>
</Row>
</Table>
```

Comment: I'll try this out and see if it works, but I think your solution is the best.

Comment: yeah for this kind of customisation this looks good otherwise i was going to recommend documentBuilder kind of solution basically setting all values yourself.

Comment: @Andreas Just one thing: The forced linebreaks don't work well when I use IndentingXMLStreamWriter. Just a heads up for anyone wondering why they get weird characters like '&#xd;' at the end of each tag if they try to pretty print this xml string to a file.

Comment: @rosenjcb `com.sun.xml.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter` is an internal class that you should **not** be using. --- And, of course, if you're using a writer that indents and wrap lines for you, you shouldn't insert line separators and indenting spaces yourself!

Comment: @Andreas Huh a bad Stack Overflow answer suggested using it I think... or maybe it was another site.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map

```
List<String> head = Arrays.asList(data.get(0));
List<Map<String,String>> output = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
    String[] element = data.get(i);
    Map<String,String> person = new HashMap<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < element.length; j++) {
        person.put(head.get(j),element[j]);
    }
    output.add(person);
}
```

output is

```html
<ArrayList>
   <item>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Age>23</Age>
      <Name>John</Name>
   </item>
   <item>
      <Sex>Female</Sex>
      <Age>19</Age>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
   </item>
   <item>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Age>18</Age>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
   </item>
</ArrayList>
```

Comment: That is not the XML the question is requesting.

Comment: @Andreas Is right but I do like it. I was actually using a similar solution that used maps.

Comment: @mavriksc You should use a LinkedHashMap to preserve the order of items.

Comment: mostly i was answering the part of the question of decomposition into a dynamic structure instead of predefined objects. some work of serelizing to the exact desired format still needed.